# Mask a form password in PHP

Tags: encryption, passwords, wamp, plaintext

After hours of googling, following videos and a failed attempt of installing SSL on my local wamp server, I am on the cusp of giving up.

So Im here to ask for help

I have a simple form, logging a user in and comparing details with a php database, the password is stored in an MD5 hash in the database.

I know md5 is insecure and https is the bast way to secure the transmission etc, but all i need here is to simply mask the password during transmission so its not visable in plain text during a wireshark capture.

The form code is:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
<fieldset>
    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there a way to set the password as something like:

```
<label for="password">Password:</label><input type=md5("password")
```

Again its just something fast and simple to implement I need.

Thanks in advance

Wayne

Comment: No, HTML doesn't support an input type of `md5`

Comment: SSL is the recommended method of transmitting passwords between browser and server

Comment: Is there any alternative options? I have already attempted to configure wamp as https and failed, and its application only needs the pw masked

Comment: Learn to configure SSL, it will be worth it.... if you have specific questions about setting up SSL, then post those; but don't try to find quick and easy alternatives, because they are never quick, easy or secure

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thank you for the reply.

But my need does not warrant SSL, it feels like bringing a warhead to a knife fight.

I just need to mask the password, and have spent 12 hours over what was afforded for the task

Comment: Or do you know of any free wamp like https servers I could use to host the basic site for the duration of packet trace?

Comment: SSL isn't a warhead, it is the most appropriate technique for securing data between browser and server, and it isn't difficult to set up..... show what you've done, and how you've configured it and we might be able to help

Comment: I followed the tutorial from here:
http://dltr.org/blog/server/573/How-to-install-SSL-on-windows-localhost-wamp
And it all worked fine I got the syntax ok at the end

But when trying to access the web page at HTTPS://localhost/test

This webpage is not available

I tried tinkering with the settings in wamp and had to remove and install again and wipe all the changes

Comment: Pitty you spent 12 hours on trying to work around, instead of spending 12 hours on moving to https

Comment: @Wayne Please remove PHP from the title and remove the PHP tag, as this is not linked to PHP.

Comment: @PaulH, I spent 12 hours trying to get SSL installed on wamps, with many uninstalls and starting from scratch, its now I have admitted its beyond my ability I am looking for an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use a javascript MD5 library like https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5 and call the md5() function on form submission.
You will not be able to do this with html code alone.

As you know, normally the md5 hashing of a password is done on the server side, by the `index.php` page in your code. The https transmission protects the password from eavesdropping. If wireshark is able to decrypt it, that is because wireshark intercepts the communication as man-in-the-middle and produces an other https certificate for the url used. The browser should warn the user that the communication is not secure because the certificate is not from a certification authority trusted by the browser. If despite this, the user continues, he should be aware that everything on his page can be modified, including the code that does the hashing.

Comment: Incredibly insecure: precisely what I meant by `don't try to find quick and easy alternatives, because they are never quick, easy or secure`

Comment: The problem of hashing on the client is that the hash becomes the new password.

Comment: @Artjom The problem of a hash becoming the new password is right and linked to not using https

Answer (score 0):

https is the proven solution of choice for login password encryption and session protection.

In case https is not possible, an alternative to prevent a password from being abused may be assymetric encryption: encrypt the password in the browser with a public key provided by your server and decrypt it on the server with the corresponding private key. A javascript library to do the encryption is https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt. Without the private key, the attacker using wireshark will not be able to decrypt the password.

The password would have to be encrypted together with 'salt', a nonce (e.g. a sequence number) from the server to prevent reuse of the cryptogram by an attacker.

A warning: read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking if you intend to use the password for a session. https is a solution again.